# wpf textbox validation with regex

Tags: c#, wpf, regex

I have a textbox in which I'm using the event TextChanged to check if the string is valid with RegEx and show a messagebox if it isnt. When testing the regex I have with online regex tool such as http://regexpal.com/, it seems to be working fine. But when I run my code, it's not working as expected. I'm never seeing the messagebox show up. Any help would be appreciated. My regex is suppose to check any digits from 0-5 before the "." with two decimals if any.

```
private void txtValInput_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     string input = (sender as TextBox).Text; //1234567

     if(!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2}$"))
     {
           MessageBox.Show("Error!, check and try again");
     }
}
```

Comment: Why arent you using your local variable input? you're creating it, so you should be using it w/ the IsMatch

Comment: @moncadad -- I've updated. still the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `()` so the regex is properly anchored, otherwise your example matches because the regex is only checking whether there are one to five digits at the start of the string - anything could come after.

```
@"^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2})$"
```

Comment: You beat me to the answer, +1.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is because you haven't encompassed your *Regular Expression* within `()`.  Without that identifier it isn't able anchor your syntax correctly.

You would want your *Expression* to look like this:

`@"^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2})$`

Keep in mind you may have also added additional complexity to your *Expression*.

To elaborate:

- `^`: Will grab the first character or line.
- `\d`: Will grab all the numeric characters.
- `$`: Will stop at end of line or last character.

I'd like to take a second with that second one.  If you actually do `\d+` it will grab all numeric characters and all that precede afterwards.  Which may make your request slightly easier; but I'm unsure of what you are searching.

Hopefully that helps, I see a *Grey 1 Answer Box* so someone else posted so you should easily find a resolution Calvin.